# Regex: how to detect a particular text, followed by a specific number?

Tags: regex

I want to use regex for the following statements:

- What are the **top 10** destination?
- What are the **top 5** destinations?
- What are the **bottom 10** destination?
- What are the **bottom 7** destinations?

How can I write regex for the above cases where *first* it detects if the user wants "top" or "bottom" destinations *and then* checks the quantity i.e 10 or 7 or 5?

I'm trying the following which isn't working.

```
(?<top>\d{2})
(?<bottom>\d{2})
```

Basically, the idea is if the user types top 10 destinations, the system will trigger a response e.g.

```
console.log("you want top 10 destinations")
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you asking for a pattern like `(top|bottom)(\d{1,2})`?

Comment: Hi, your understand it correct. I tested the one you mentioned on regex101.com but it doesn't seem to be working. Just type "top 10" or "bottom 5" there. Thx

Comment: I forgot a space...

Comment: Year i figured it out. Thx and let me test it further.

Comment: `(?<top>\d{2})` looks like Perl syntax for named capture groups. JavaScript doesn't even support named captures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could be using the following regex

```
.*((?:top|bottom)\s+\d+).*
```

And replace it by the following sentence

```
You want the $1 destinations
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8YohP1/2/)**

Comment: What's the point of those `.*` thingies? Those don't do anything.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Hi, it's just to be able to replace more easily. It's to exclude those. Look at the demo, remove `.*` and see what happens